# How to correctly convert MultiValueMap to Json with Jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I am trying to return a Json created from the queries of a request.

### For example:

`url.com?field1=value1&field2=value2&field1=value3`

- Should return:

```
"queryString": {
    "field1": [
      "value1",
      "value3"
    ],
    "field2": "value2"
}
```

- But what I have is:

```
"queryString": {
    "field1": [
        "value1",
        "value3"
    ],
    "field2": [
        "value2"
    ]
}
```

For **field2** I want the value to be **"value2"** and not as an array **["value2"]**.

---

The code is:

```
@JsonGetter("queryString")
public MultiValueMap<String, String> getQueryString() {
    String queryString = Optional.ofNullable(httpRequest.getQueryString()).orElse("");

    // queryString is for our example : field1=value1&field2=value2&field1=value3
    return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("?" + queryString).build().getQueryParams();
}
```

Should I use a different Collection? Which one?

- Precision : I do not know what type to expect for the fields, it can be either a `String` or `List<String>`.

Answer (score 2):

A `MultiValueMap` by definition stores a key and a list of values, so it makes sense that the serialization would look like `{"key":["value1", "value2"]}`.

Assuming this is what you want to do, here's a few ways to do this:

1. It seems to me you know what you expect to know the types of `field1` and `field2` so you could define a class to nicely capture that information:

```java
    class MyClass {
        private final List<String> field1;
        private final String field2;

        public MyClass(List<String> field1, String field2) {
            this.field1 = field1;
            this.field2 = field2;
        }

        public List<String> getField1() {
            return field1;
        }

        public String getField2() {
            return field2;
        }
    }

    @JsonGetter("queryString")
    public MyClass getQueryString() {
        String queryString = "url.com?field1=value1&field2=value2&field1=value3";
        MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams =  UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(queryString).build().getQueryParams();
        return new MyClass(queryParams.get("field1"), queryParams.getFirst("field2"));
    }
```

2. A quick and dirty solution would be to simply convert the `MultiValueMap<String, String>` to `Map<String, Object>`, which will get the serialization you desire (based on [`MultiValueMapAdapter.toSingleValueMap()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMapAdapter.java#L96):

```java
    @JsonGetter("queryString")
    public Map<String, Object> getQueryString() {
        String queryString = "url.com?field1=value1&field2=value2&field1=value3";
        MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams =  UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(queryString).build().getQueryParams();
        Map<String, Object> singleValueMap = CollectionUtils.newLinkedHashMap(queryParams.size());
        for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : queryParams.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() != null && !entry.getValue().isEmpty()) {
                if (entry.getValue().size() == 1) {
                    singleValueMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().get(0));
                } else {
                    singleValueMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
        return singleValueMap;
    }
```

3. Depending on how you're using this you could also define a [custom serializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization).

Note there are additional edge cases in these examples you may need to handle, such as nulls and empty lists.

Comment: I will try to create a custom serializer, if I can, otherwise, I'll use the "quick and dirty solution". Thanks,